# Chrome API / Selenium to check if web requests are generated ONLY by extension

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I am developing test automation using Selenium with Java. My job is to test if some third party extension works properly or not. Meaning suppose if that extension sends some web requests then verify it using Selenium Java project. Now I have added my another extension to parse all web requests(requests generated by host web and extensions also). But I don't want to do that.

> So, Is there any provision in Chrome API / Selenium to check if web
>   requests are generated **ONLY** by extension?